# Can you run windows containers with portainer.io

Tags: portainer

If i try to use and docker image or template, it say's the image does not exist. My docker is running as windows containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Altough you'll need to run Windows specific images. In the default App Templates list, you'll want to search for templates with the Windows icon.

Comment: Hey Tony, I was able to run windows images after I reinstalled docker. For some reason it was not letting me.